# Vue.js Update child component data from within parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I update the data in a child component from within the parent? I am trying to update the autores property from within the parent and have that update the child data. Currently nothing happens, I don't think I have the data linked correctly. If I add it as data to the parent component then the parent re-renders when the code runs and no results can be seen.

Parent:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input @keyup="editName(lender.id, $event)">

            <autocomplete-suggestions :autores="[]"></autocomplete-suggestions>

    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    export default {
        props: ['lender'],

        data(){
            return {

            }
        },

        methods: {
            editName: function(lenderid, event) {

                var self = this;

                    axios.post('/lenders/autocomplete', {...})
                        .then(function (data) {

                            self.autores = data.data.suggestions;

                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log("Error occurred getting the autocomplete");
                        });


            },
        },
        watch: {

        },
        mounted: function() {

        }
    };
</script>
```

Child:

```
<template>
    <div class="list">
        <div v-for="(res, i) in autores">{{res}}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    export default {
        props: ['autores'],
        data(){
            return {

            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

**Update:**

If I change my code in parent to:

```
data(){
    return {
        autores:[]
    }
},
```

and:

```
<autocomplete-suggestions :autores="autores"></autocomplete-suggestions>
```

Then simply whenever I update `this.autores`, whatever text has been typed into the text box in parent in reset, as if it were rerendering the whole component. How can ths be stopped?

Comment: You need to declare `autores` in parent `data`. And then pass to child component `:autores="autores"`

Comment: @ittus The problem then is that whenever I update the value of `autores`, it causes the parent to rerender. Then whatever text has been typed in the text box is simply reset back to the start. How do you update data in parent without it rerendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input @keyup="editName(lender.id, $event)">
    <autocomplete-suggestions ref="autocompleteSuggestions"></autocomplete-suggestions>
  </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
  export default {
    props: ['lender'],
    methods: {
      editName: function (lenderid, event) {
        var self = this;
        axios.post('/lenders/autocomplete', {...})
          .then(function (data) {
            self.$refs.autocompleteSuggestions.autores = data.data.suggestions;
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error occurred getting the autocomplete");
          });
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

Child:

```
<template>
  <div className="list">
    <div v-for="(res, i) in autores">{{res}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      autores: []
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. There is still no update in the child component...?

Comment: i'm sorry, should be like this:
`self.$refs.autocompleteSuggestions.autores = data.data.suggestions;`